# Facebook login from react native app with symfony server

Tags: android, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api, react-native

I am trying to set up a proper facebook login in my react native app. For now I have it working in a pure webview with oauth login to my server but I want to use the native facebook login to be able to take advantage of the facebook app.

I am using the following libraries:

### Server side

- https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle
- https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle
- https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

### App side

- https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login

So my facebook login is perfectly functional on my website as well as on my app in a webview for OAuth by calling `/oauth/v2/auth` in a webview and handling the token.

But it is kinda messy because in the webview you have to type your full email + password combo.

So right now I'm just getting an authorization error when calling `/login/facebook-check` in a webview on the Login success event (by the native plugin), I could use some help to finish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it work. The hack was to use all the existing services to work together.

I made a custom controller. Some security checks are needed but still this works:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/facebook-connect/{accessToken}", name="api_facebook_connect", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @Rest\View()
 */
public function facebookLoginAction($accessToken, Request $request)
{
    $token = new OAuthToken($accessToken);
    $token->setResourceOwnerName('facebook');

    $oauthUserProvider = $this->get('app.oauth.provider.user_provider');
    $ressourceOwnerMap = $this->get('hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main');
    $userChecker = new UserChecker();

    $oauthProvider = new OAuthProvider($oauthUserProvider, $ressourceOwnerMap, $userChecker);
    $token = $oauthProvider->authenticate($token);
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

    $client = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('AppBundle:Client')->findOneBy([], ['id' => 'DESC']);

    $oauth2server = $this->get('fos_oauth_server.server');
    $accessToken = $oauth2server->createAccessToken($client, $this->getUser(), 'user', 3600);

    return $accessToken;
}
```

Will update this as I clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to properly handle the server-side part, however here are a few details about how we integrated Facebook login in one of our app:

- We first started by using https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login but later switched to https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk, which is maintained by Facebook and allow to access to other Facebook services (in particular, we used the Share API)
- In both case (react-native-fbsdk or not), the flow was like this:

  - We have a Connect with Facebook button (a normal button, nothing fancy - we're not using the one provided by the modules).
  - When clicked, we call the Login method with the appropriate permissions. This should work out of the box, meaning that you'll have either a webview displayed (if you don't have the Facebook app) or the native Facebook app shown.
  - If the user declines the login to the app, nothing will happen.
  - If the user accepts, the app will receive the Access Token that can be used to issue calls to the Facebook API on the behalf of the user. This looks like this using react-native-fbsdk:

    ```
    // This can be put in a Facebook login button component or a service,
    // and should be called when the user wants to connect with Facebook
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions).then((result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        this.props.onCancel();
        return;
      }

      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
        this.props.onLogin(data);
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.warn('Facebook Error', error);
    });
    ```
  - We then send the access token to our server which is able to fetch the profile of the user via the Facebook Graph API, creating a user account on the server if needed (i.e: if it's the first time the user log on).

    ```
    // Called once we got the access token from the data in the previous
    // step (this.props.onLogin(data)).
    loginWithFacebook(facebookAccessToken) {
      return fetch(`${apiHost}/api/login/facebook`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          // We pass the access token using the Authorization header:
          Authorization: `Bearer ${facebookAccessToken}`,
        },
      }).then(() => {
        // Whatever, for example get the user info returned by the server
        // and store them.
      });
    }
    ```
  - On the server, we get the Access Token from the headers and use it to get the user profile (populating the account of the user for our app, for example with his avatar and name) and associate the user account with the facebook id of the user.

If the user have the Facebook app and already accepted the app, nothing will be asked to him the next time he tries to log in. You just click on the login button and get logged to the app :)
If the user don't have the Facebook app, the Facebook SDK always display a webview with the login page.

Hope this can help!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, what interests me is the "fetch" part that HWI is already doing, and then redirecting to the create/fetch user from database that FOSUser is already doing. I have all the pieces I just don't know how to place them